# How to check if at least one checkbox is checked in the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form with 4 checkbox fields. In order for user to process the form they have to check at least one checkbox. If none of the checkboxes are checked then user will get the message about this error. I have on submit function where I would like to validate this criteria. However, here is my function:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myFrm', saveFrm);
function saveFrm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var frmData = $(this).serialize(),
        submitBtn = $(this).closest('form').find(':submit'),
        messageBox = $(this).closest('form').find('.message-submit'),
        ckLen = $('#myFrm input[type=checkbox]:checked');

    if(ckLen === 0){
       alert('At least on checkbox has to be checked.');
    }else{
       // Save form
    }
}
```

Code above should work just fine but one thing that I was wondering is this line of code:

```
ckLen = $('#myFrm input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

is there a way to use `$(this)` instead of hard coded form id ?

Comment: well you already do it to find the submit button and message box..... not sure how it is any different

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on `$(this)`. You also have to take *length* property from the object to make the condition work properly:

```
ckLen = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```